# How to end a program when file does not exist rather than having a large block of text?

Tags: java

I'm trying to end a program without having a block of unseemly text.
I've looked through a few other threads with this topic and have tried to do what was suggested but for some reason it's not working. Thank you for any help.

Error when ran:

[image: --]

My code to end if file does not exist:

[image: --]

Comment: Move line 60 to line 68. And DON'T POST CODE AS AN IMAGE.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh thank you ~ Now that I look at it and it was pointed out by you, I understand why. -facepalms-

Comment: Many things are obvious once pointed out by others. Next time read the stack trace more carefully, it does tell you the error (from your code) started at line 60. Clearly the check if the file exists is after that line, so...

Comment: Please don't edit the title to say "solved." Instead, just accept an answer. If the answer that someone else posted isn't what solved it for you, you can always add your own answer and accept that.

Comment: @yshavit Ah thank you. I'm pretty new to this website so I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elliott Frisch said under your post, the solution for your problem is to move the line

```
Scanner fInput = new Scanner(inputFile);
```

under the if-statement (line 68).

**But why?**

When you initialise a Scanner with a File-Object it will try to open a stream to that file. If the file doesn't exist, a FileNotFoundException will be thrown.